# FreeRTOS on STM32CubeIDE has some errors which I can't solve

Tags: c, stm32, freertos

Recently I've done a program on 'CubeIDE'. After setting the wanted features and generating, it shows some errors related to `FreeRTOS` which is:

> 'ListItem_t {aka struct xLIST_ITEM}' has no member named
> 'pxContainer'; did you mean 'pvContainer'?

I would like to know how I can deal with this problem.

Comment: Hmmm... the error tells you everything. Your code tries to use the member `pxContainer`but the struct has no member `pxContainer`. It appears that the struct has a `pvContainer`... did you make a simple typo?

Answer (score 0):

ListItem_t actually does have a member called pxContainer.  See https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/V10.4.3/include/list.h#L149